# Finding the step response of a RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, laplace-transform

For a homework problem, I am supposed to find the step response v(t) for the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff0I8o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where the input is \$v_s(t) = 2u(t)\$, and the response \$v(t)\$ is the voltage across the capicator C1.

So, here's what I did.  I converted the circuit to the s-domain and constructed a transfer function:

$$\frac{V(s)}{V_s(s)}=\frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{R_1+\frac{1}{sC}||(R_2+sL)}$$

And then simplifying the function and solving for V(s):

$$V(s) = \frac{LCs^2+R_2Cs+1}{R_1LC^2s^3+(R_1R_2C^2+LC)s^2+(R_1C+R_2C)s} V_s(s)$$

Since the input is converted to \$\frac{2}{s}\$ in the s-domain:

$$V(s) = \frac{LCs^2+R_2Cs+1}{R_1LC^2s^3+(R_1R_2C^2+LC)s^2+(R_1C+R_2C)s} \frac{2}{s}$$

Which does not make sense because then the final value would be:

$$v(\infty)= \lim_{s \to 0} sV(s) = \infty$$

Which is impossible because you cannot have infinite voltage.  There has to be a limit.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is good that you did a reality check.

Comment: Vxs8122-I suppose you know that the step response is a function in the time domain. Do you consider the problem as solved if you find the final value only?

Comment: @LvW I know that, the final value is just for reality check.  The solving part is incomplete because the final value did not make sense.

Comment: @Vxs8122,OK-I see. Hence, you either need to solve the diff. equation of the system in the time domain or you need to apply the inverse Laplace transform to the function H(s)/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the approach of the transfer function:

$$\frac{V(s)}{V_s(s)}=\frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{R_1+\frac{1}{sC}||(R_2+sL)}$$

when the correct is:

$$
\frac{V(s)}{V_s(s)}=\frac{\frac{1}{sC}||(R_2+sL)}{R_1+\frac{1}{sC}||(R_2+sL)}
$$

according to the voltage divider.

Comment: Thank you.  I just realized that mistake just few minutes ago.